# How to change style of MUI InputBase when is disabled?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, frontend

I have gone through so many answers and documentations, but none of the tentatives is working for me. I am very noob to javascript/mui library, so I am trying everything that I am finding to be honest.

I need to keep this `disabled={props.viewer == true}`, this is version of my package `"@mui/material": "^5.10.11"`

This is my code:

```
<Inputbase_wrapper>
    <a href={card.familyLink} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <InputBase
            placeholder=''
            fullWidth={true}
            value={card.familyLink||''}
            disabled={props.viewer == true}
        />
    </a>
</Inputbase_wrapper>
```

I tried all of this `sx` below, but none of them applied the style needed, what should I do?

1.

```
sx={{ "&.MuiInputBase-input": {
        "&:disabled": {
            fontFamily: 'Poppins', fontSize: '14px', textDecoration: 'underline', color: "blue", cursor: 'pointer'
        }
    }
    }}
```

2. 

```
sx={{
        "&.Mui-disabled": {
            fontFamily: 'Poppins', fontSize: '14px', textDecoration: 'underline', color: "blue", cursor: 'pointer'
        }
    }}
```

In this one I tried: `"&.Mui-disabled"`, `"&:disabled"`, `"Mui-disabled &"`, etc